# Symfony2 Forms: Generating checkboxes

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

currently i have a form, that generates a Drop-Down-Select from my category-entity:

```
        $builder
            ->add('category', 'entity',
                    array('class' => 'TrackerMembersBundle:Category',
                            'property' => 'title',));
```

Now i want to generate checkboxes instead, where i can select more than one option...i searched the symfony2 documentation, but could not find an easy way to do it directly from my Entity.Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding `'multiple' => true` to the option array (the last one where class and property are) gives you a multi-select.

Then you could override the choice_widget block, using [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form).

Something like this might work:

```
{% block choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for choice, label in choices %}
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ choice }}"{% if _form_is_choice_selected(form, choice) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
            {{ label|trans }}
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

Answer (score 10):

Because `EntityType` has parent the `ChoiceType`, you can use any option from the `choice` type.

In your case, configuring your `category` field as following would render checkboxes:

```
$builder
    ->add('category', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'TrackerMembersBundle:Category',
        'property' => 'title',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
    )
);
```

Note the usage of `multiple` AND `expanded` in the options.

Comment: the multiple and expanded did not have any effect on the dropdown.

Comment: That's not normal then :) I tested in my own project before answering you, and it worked well. Do you have errors messages or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
       $builder
        ->add('category', 'checkbox',
                array('class' => 'TrackerMembersBundle:Category',
                        'property' => 'title',));#
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html

Comment: i tried this before , i get: The options "class", "property", "multiple" do not exist

Comment: This won't work. He still needs the `entity` formType, not the `checkbox` type.